# Xamarin.Forms Bluetooth Label Printing

Tags: c#, .net, printing, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

Currently I have an Xamarin.Forms application and I should add feature for printing. More details, I should connect with Bluetooth to label printer and print there bar code (but I don't think content matters for this post).

Printer that I am using is [RPP320](http://www.rongtatech.com/products-look-89.html).

Can anybody suggest framework with which I can proceed? Would be very helpful if you can link any source code or sample open source application.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**
What I found is an application RTPrinter, which comes from printer brand producer, but still I am missing any other information.

**Edit 2:**
I found framework "LinkOS_Xamarin_SDK", I am not sure if it can work for me, but I will try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found is a framework [Blacksun.XamForms](https://github.com/angelcalvasp/Blacksun.XamForms), which works great for my case. Easy API and it's open source.